# how to make a string case insensitive

Tags: android

I have one edittext and listview having some values. While typing text in edittext the listview contents will change according to the values typed inside edittext.

Now the problem is, the string is in case sensitive. ie, If the original text is `Apparel`, then if we type `apparel` or `appa` the original text is not displaying.

I want to make the string search case insensitive.

My code is,

```
private List<SearchList> searchTerms(List<SearchList> search_list, String s) {
    List<SearchList> matches = new ArrayList<SearchList>();
    for (SearchList search_lists : search_list) {
        if (search_lists.search_term.contains(s)) {
            matches.add(search_lists);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this. I have tried a lot.

Comment: Why dont you use `toLowerCase()` with string

Comment: @Clairvoyant : I have tried that. But not worked

Comment: can you show the code what you have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**string contains();** function is case sensitive.
And from your question, I've noticed that your list contains items with Capital letters as well in it. 
So apply **toLowerCase()** to both side would cut it.

```
if (search_lists.search_term.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) 
{
    matches.add(search_lists);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to lower() a string:

```
private List<SearchList> searchTerms(List<SearchList> search_list, String s) {
    List<SearchList> matches = new ArrayList<SearchList>();
    for (SearchList search_lists : search_list) {
        if (search_lists.search_term.contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
            matches.add(search_lists);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do as like and compare, Hope it will work :)

```
   EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   String editTextString=editText.getText().toString();
   editTextString.equalsIgnoreCase(yourCompare);
```

Comment: This wouldn't achieve the required functionality as Jithin wants it so that the editTextString is a substring of a particular search term.